# Styling tables in emails

Tags: html, css, email

I have been looking around the internet to understand what the best is to style a table in my emails.

As far as I know, CSS is sensitive when it comes to email.

But then, when it comes to my tables, better to style them with CSS or HTML?

Basically, should I go for line like this:

```
<td style="text-align: center; width: 600px; height: 35px; background-color: #dcdcdc">
```

Or a line like that:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#dcdcdc" width: "600px" height="35px">
```

Or it doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can vary depending on the email client.

For safety's sake you can do both but I would recommend applying width, bgcolor and align using the second method and then any other styles using a style tag.

i.e.

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#dcdcdc" width="600" height="35" style="font-family:Arial;"></td>
```